# Can a factory method pattern use different overloads

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-method

I have a use case where I need to build a factory class that returns different concrete types based on an enum being passed. However, each of those types require different constructor parameters. So, in that case does it make sense to have multiple methods with different signatures, or is that not a factory pattern at all?

I'm thinking something like

```
class CarFactory
{
  public ModelS TeslaMaker (List<Battery> batteries){/*return ModelS*/}
  public Mustang FordMaker (Engine engine) {/*return a Mustang*/}
}
```

instead of say

```
    class CarFactory
    {
      public Car GetCar(CarType carType) //where CarType is an enum (Ford=0,Tesla=1)
      { 
        switch(carType) 
        {  case CarType.Ford: return new Mustang(); }//just an example
      }
    }
```

**EDIT**:
In my case I actually need to return a family of classes. So, if it's a Tesla, return a ModelS, a ModelSService, ModelSWarranty, etc. So I'm going to go with the Abstract Factory approach which will wrap the suggestions given here.

Comment: The first one doesn't actually have the enum part, though.

Comment: @Nyerguds - yes, which is why I was doubtful if it was even a factory pattern.

Answer (score 4):

> So, in that case does it make sense to have multiple methods with different signatures, or is that not a factory pattern at all?

It doesn't make any sense to have a factory with specific methods. If your client code has to decide which specific method should it use, why wouldn't it call the specific car's constructor directly? In your example, factory methods would merely be wrappers over specific constructors.

On the other hand having a single factory method that is called with an enum gives your client a chance to decide dynamically which car should it create, the decision could for example be based on a database query.

There are some possible ways around your current approach.

One option would be to have a hierarchy of classes that represent constructor parameters. You don't even need the enum then because the parameter type is enough to infer which specific car should be created:

```
public abstract class CarCreationParams { }

public class FordCreationParams : CarCreationParams
{
    public Engine engine;
}

...

public class CarFactory
{
    public Car GetCar( CarCreationParams parms )
    {
        if ( parms is FordCreationParams )
            return new Ford( ((FordCreationParams)parms).engine );
        ...
```

Another option would be to think whether you **really** need your Fords to be created with external engines (aggregation) or rather they own their engines (composition). In the latter case, you would expose parameterless constructors to your specific car types:

```
public class Ford : Car
{
     public Engine engine;

     // car is composed of multiple parts, including the engine
     public Ford()
     { 
          this.engine = new FordEngine();
     }
```

which makes the implementation of the factory much easier.

Comment: Thank you. This is an excellent answer. Implementing it like you said with composition could also work. However, I was thinking of passing in a Dependence Injection container into a factory method and letting that wire up the DI container instead of returning an object. This is because there are a family of classes I need to wire up and not just one object. However, that seems to go against the seperation of concerns principle in the factory (why does the factory care about the DI container). So I guess I need to use something like "Abstract Factory" in my case.

Comment: Read my tutorial on implementing a factory that could possibly be using a DI container internally, http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2016/01/di-factories-and-composition-root.html

Comment: Actually your tutorial uses DI externally in the client side. I will be doing the same, however, i was thinking of passing in the DI as a reference parameter into the internals of the factory, so the factory augments the DI container instead of returning concrete classes itself.

Comment: Passing a DI container around sounds like an anti-pattern. The architecture should never make use of DI directly, this is what the Composition Root tries to achieve. This makes it possible to think of a DI container as something that only supports your architecture rather than something that your architecture is bound to.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not a good example of factor pattern. Rather if your Car class is dependent on different types of Components you can have factories for those too. E.G For Car and Engine you can have like:

```
    public interface ICar
    {
        IEngine Engine { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mustang : ICar
    {
        private IEngine _engine = EngineFactory.GetEngine(EngineType.Mustang);
        public IEngine Engine
        {
            get { return _engine; }
            set { _engine = value; }
        }
    } 

    public class CarFactory
    {
        public ICar GetCar(CarType carType)
        {
            switch (carType)
            { case CarType.Ford: return new Mustang(); }
        }
    }
```

Similarly for Engine

```
    public interface IEngine { }

    public class MustangEngine : IEngine
    {

    }

    public class EngineFactory
    {

        public static IEngine GetEngine(EngineType engine)
        {
            switch (engine)
            { case EngineType.Mustang: return new MustangEngine(); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'm going to use an Abstract Factory in my case since I have a family of objects to create.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need different parameters for object creation(batteries for Tesla or Engine for Ford) you can choose between different solutions:
 - pass all of these parameters while creating a factory  - it will be specific factory for all types of car with such available details;

```
class SpecificCarFactory
{
  public SpecificCarFactory(IList<Battery> batteries, IList<Engine> engines)
  {
    //save batteries etc into local  properties
  }
  public Car GetCar(CarType carType)
  { 
    switch(carType) 
    {  case CarType.Ford: return new Mustang(_engines.First()); }
  }
}
```

- encapsulate parameters into class object and get them from factory method parameter;

  ```
  class CarFactory
  {
        public Car GetCar(CarDetail carDetail) //where CarDetails                  encapsulates all the possible car details
        { 
               switch(carDetail.type) 
               {  case CarType.Ford: return new Mustang(carDetail.Engine);//just an example
               }
        }
  }
  ```

Comment: Encapsulation is good, but since each type needs different parameters, there's one step one shouldn't forget : check the parameters that were defined into the passed object (if you don't it's just a miracle recipe for `NullReferenceException`)

Comment: Of course that should be done  by using assertions or CodeContracts framework.

Comment: I thought about this initially but decided it was a bit of a mess passing around everything when I only needed a subset of the parameters.

Comment: Than you also need factories for all the resources that are required for car creation and than  pass those factories as a dependency into car factory. In that case you will just need catType for factory method.

Comment: That is true. I'm thinking of using part of this suggestion by having the abstract factory (the factory of factory) receive all parameters and then delegating a subset of parameters to the child factories.

Comment: This is possible but be aware of complexity - keep the things flexible but simple as much  as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is factory pattern.
factory pattern says to create factories of Object but let subclass decide the way to instantiate the object .
This is true in your case your deciding based on type of Enum